# current time using javascript not grabbing correct location

Tags: javascript, jquery

Running a script to get current time for two specific locations. One time is for Mountain Time and the other is for East Coast Time. I am running into an issue where the Mountain Time clock is displaying time based on Pacific Standard Time if a user is based in a PST location. Rather than having PST is there a way for me to make sure that the two clocks are only getting MT and ET and taking into consideration daylight savings time as well?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function timeDisplay() {
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
  //var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
  var meridiem = " ";

  if(hours >= 12){
    hours = hours - 12;
    meridiem = "pm";
  }
  else{
    meridiem = "am";
  }
  if(hours === 0){
    hours = 12;
  }
  if(hours < 10){
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }
  if(minutes < 10){
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }

  var clockDiv = document.getElementById('stat');
  clockDiv.innerText = hours + ":" + minutes + meridiem;
  }

  timeDisplay();
  setInterval(timeDisplay, 1000);



  function newYorkTimeDisplay(offset) {
  var currentTime = new Date();  
  currentTime.setHours(currentTime.getHours()+offset); 

  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
  //var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
  var meridiem = " ";

  if(hours >= 12){
    hours = hours - 12;
    meridiem = "pm";
  }
  else{
    meridiem = "am";
  }
  if(hours === 0){
    hours = 12;
  }
  if(hours < 10){
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }
  if(minutes < 10){
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }

  var newYorkDiv = document.getElementById('newYork');      
  newYorkDiv.innerText = hours + ":" + minutes + meridiem; 
}

newYorkTimeDisplay(+2);
setInterval(newYorkTimeDisplay, 1000, +2); 

});
```

Any help on this is appreciated. Trying to figure out what I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the user's current UTC timezone offset and subtract it from New York's Timezone Offset.

```
var tz_offset = (new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/100) - 3;
newYorkTimeDisplay(tz_offset);
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function timeDisplay() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    //var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    var meridiem = " ";

    if (hours >= 12) {
      hours = hours - 12;
      meridiem = "pm";
    } else {
      meridiem = "am";
    }
    if (hours === 0) {
      hours = 12;
    }
    if (hours < 10) {
      hours = "0" + hours;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
      minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }

    var clockDiv = document.getElementById('stat');
    clockDiv.innerText = hours + ":" + minutes + meridiem;
  }

  timeDisplay();
  setInterval(timeDisplay, 1000);



  function newYorkTimeDisplay(offset) {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    currentTime.setHours(currentTime.getHours() + offset);

    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    //var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    var meridiem = " ";

    if (hours >= 12) {
      hours = hours - 12;
      meridiem = "pm";
    } else {
      meridiem = "am";
    }
    if (hours === 0) {
      hours = 12;
    }
    if (hours < 10) {
      hours = "0" + hours;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
      minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }

    var newYorkDiv = document.getElementById('newYork');
    newYorkDiv.innerText = hours + ":" + minutes + meridiem;
  }

  var tz_offset = (new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/100) - 3;
  newYorkTimeDisplay(tz_offset);
  
  setInterval(newYorkTimeDisplay, 1000, +2);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=newYork></div>
<div id=stat></div>
```